# Add node on click on another node with d3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Recently I tried mastering the d3js library (which is great) and I am trying to do the easiest stuff but for some reason it doesn't work correctly at all. I did look at related issues but none could help me to find my problem.

The setup is simple, I have a force layout with only one node and no link. When the user clicks on that node, I would like to add a new node that gets linked to the node that was clicked. Here is my code so far. The first added node has a very random position and after that I keep having a message "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__data__' of null".

Thank you for your help !

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>D3 test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="viz">
    </div>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var w = 800;
        var h = 800;
        var padding = 100;
        var svg = d3.select("#viz")
                    .append("svg")
                    .attr("width", w)
                    .attr("height", h);
        var nodes = [{name:"n0"}];
        var links = []; 
        var force = d3.layout.force()
                        .size([w, h])
                        .linkDistance([100])
                        .charge([-30])
                        .start();
        var link = svg.selectAll(".link"),
            node = svg.selectAll(".node");

        update();

        function update() {
            force.nodes(nodes)
                  .links(links)
                  .start();
            link = link.data(force.links(), function(d) {return d.source.name + "-" + d.target.name;})
                            .enter()
                            .insert("line", ".node")
                            .attr("class", "link")
                            .style("stroke", "red")
                            .style("stroke-width", 2);

            node = node.data(force.nodes(), function(d) {return d.name;})
                            .enter()
                            .append("circle")
                            .attr("class", "node")
                            .attr("r", 10)
                            .style("fill", "black")
                            .on("click", function(d) {
                                var n = {name:"n"+nodes.length};
                                nodes.push(n);
                                links.push({source:d, target:n});
                                update();
                            })
                            .call(force.drag);
        }
        force.on("tick", function() {
            link.attr("x1", function(d) {return d.source.x;})
                    .attr("y1", function(d) {return d.source.y;})
                    .attr("x2", function(d) {return d.target.x;})
                    .attr("y2", function(d) {return d.target.y;});
            node.attr("cx", function(d) {return d.x})
                    .attr("cy", function(d) {return d.y});
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: [This example](http://bl.ocks.org/benzguo/4370043) does almost exactly what you want. On a general note, the force layout is not the best way to get started with D3. Stick to the easy stuff first :)

Comment: Ok thanks for the advice ! I can see why your example works, still can't see what's faulty in mine though... If you have any idea I'd love to know because it's really bugging me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a reason that I can't explain, it works perfectly when I change this bit

```
node = node.data(force.nodes(), function(d) {return d.name;}).enter()...
```

to this

```
node = node.data(force.nodes(), function(d) {return d.name;})
node.enter()...
```

And do the same to the "link" selection

I guess it has to do with enter selections and co.

Comment: The reason is that in `tick`, with the first version you use the entered selection (new nodes only) whereas on the second version you use the whole selection (all nodes).